# jQuery keypress .val() returns previous value after function runs

Tags: jquery

I have a strange issue that I can't seem to figure out:

This keydown/keypress function only returns the previous value (i.e. first time returns nothing, second time returns first value, third time returns second value, etc...)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZRPfb/

Can someone enlighten me as to why **keydown** and **keypress** dont work, but **keyup** works??

```
 $(".modal-body #rowDownload").unbind().on('keypress',function(){
    var numRows = $(".modal-body #rowDownload").val();
    // var numRows = $(this).val();
    alert(numRows);

    if (typeof numRows !== 'number') return;

});
```

Comment: thanks, but both dont work.

Comment: You need to be using `keyup` instead. Check out the docs to see the differences between the two.

Comment: @Zenith thanks! i actually just realized this, but still interested in why keypress and keydown didn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer**

Use `.keyup()` event instead

**Here's why**

This is the normal behavior of javascript. The function you call on keypress is running before the value itself is added.

Let me demonstrate it to you. When you do `.preventDefault()` on keypress, what will happen? The character will not be inserted. Would it be logical that the code behind add the character, then run over `preventDefault()` and remove the character? I don't think so, that's why the function runs before adding the character.

It will work with `.keyup()` because the character is already added.

Hope this clarifies a little bit!

Comment: Note keyup() doesn't work on Safari/IOS.

Answer (score 3):

I have checked the link. Use the 'keyup' event. It works. This is due to when you use the keydown or keypress event then the event function runs before the value of the input tag is updated because it is keydown. If you try the code by pressing the key for sometime then you will see the function runs immediately. But on keyup the function will run after the key is released and updated therefore.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an addon to `Karl-André Gagnon's` answer. Yeah, It's because of execution order. So use [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event instead of [`keypress`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) to solve this.

If you are persistent to do it with keypress, you can run remaining code inside a timeout after a narrow interval.

Eg:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input.selectorclass', function(e){
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log($(that).val());
    }, 1);
});
```